# Issue with autoplay of canva video

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a canva video to my react js application.
Everything is good except for autoplay.

I have tried multiple method to this and failed every time.

sample code I use is provided below.
Also the video is configured with autoplay in canva.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const CanvaEmbed = () => {



  const iframeRef: any = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // // When the component mounts, play the video in the iframe
    // if (iframeRef.current) {
    //   iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(
    //     '{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}',
    //     "*"
    //   );
    // }
    // Check if iframeRef is defined and if the iframe contentWindow exists
    if (iframeRef.current && iframeRef.current.contentWindow) {
      // Simulate a click event on the iframe
      iframeRef.current.contentWindow.postMessage(
        '{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}',
        "*"
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        width: "100%",
        height: 0,
        paddingTop: "56.2500%",
        paddingBottom: 0,
        boxShadow: "0 2px 8px 0 rgba(63, 69, 81, 0.16)",
        marginTop: "1.6em",
        marginBottom: "0.9em",
        overflow: "hidden",
        borderRadius: "8px",
        willChange: "transform",
      }}
    >
      <iframe
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          border: "none",
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
        }}
        src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAFrtc9Jpbs/watch?embed"
        allowFullScreen
        allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
        ref={iframeRef}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CanvaEmbed;
```

this is the component used.
It would be great if someone could help me on this.

Thank you all.